# difference between consulting and consultancy

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What is the difference between consulting and consultancy,  if I want to talk about the activity of consultant? Should I say consulting services or consultancy services ?

Many thanks in advance.
FF

---

So here is some of my research on behalf of the original asker:

From the Cambridge Dictionary

> [consulting](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consulting)
>
> noun [ U ]
>
> the activity or business of giving expert advice about a particular subject:
>
> *This is an introductory course for graduates who are considering a career in consulting.*
>
> **financial/IT/management, etc. consulting** *Management consulting helps the world's leading organizations become even more effective.*
>
> *a consulting business/company/firm*

> [consultancy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consultancy)
>
> noun
>
> [ U ]
>
> the activity of giving expert advice on a particular subject:
>
> *It provides a range of educational services to the state, including school inspections and consultancy.*
>
> *a consultancy company/firm/group*
>
> *consultancy work/services He does part-time consultancy work.*

From the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English

> **[con‧sult‧ing](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/consulting)**<sup>1</sup> /kənˈsʌltɪŋ/ **noun** [**uncountable**]
>
> the service of providing advice to companies
>
> Examples from the Corpus
>
> **consulting**
>
> • By 1995 he wants the company to earn 20 percent of its revenues from services such as **consulting**, software and management.
>
> • Even management consultants have found a role in environmental **consulting**.

> **[con‧sul‧tan‧cy](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/consultancy)** /kənˈsʌltənsi/ ●○○ **AWL noun** (*plural* **consultancies**)
>
> **1** [**countable**] a company that gives advice on a particular subject
>
> a management consultancy
>
> a consultancy firm
>
> **2** [**uncountable**] advice that a company is paid to provide
>
> consultancy fees
>
> Examples from the Corpus
>
> [...]
>
> • The group's flagship **consultancy** business was again its biggest contributor, delivering revenue of £47.3m, up 20 per cent.
>
> [...]
>
> • The group's long-term aim is to get into non-Bull sites to deliver its **consultancy** and networking services.

Evidently, both words are equally capable of being **nouns** (the LDOCE doesn't even list "adjective" as a noteworthy part of speech), and apart from the countable use of *consultancy* for "an advice-giving business", there is significant overlap between them in the sense of "activity or service of giving advice". As seemingly proven by the Cambridge examples, when the words are used attributively, it's not exactly clear where there's any difference at all. Is a "consulting firm" any different from a "consultancy firm"?

So why should one of them be chosen over the other and what would be the semantic or collocational requirements for such choosing?

Answer (score 1):

[*Consultancy*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/consultancy) is a noun while [*consulting*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/consulting) is an adjective. Here are Oxford's entries:

> **consultancy** (*noun*)
> A professional practice that gives expert advice within a particular field
>
> **consulting** (*adj.*)
> Engaged in the business of giving expert advice to people working in a professional or technical field

The definitions are very close, but *consulting* is the better word. This is because it is directly describing the type of service.

*Consultancy* is not directly describing the type but instead saying the services are of a consultancy—a minor difference but a difference nonetheless. In the *consultancy* case, it's more correct to say *the consultancy's services*.

Comment: How about consultation?

Answer (score -1):

*Consultancy* is a noun, and *consulting* is an adjective in this sense. I have seen both being used to refer to services but I think that *consulting* sounds better