# Consultancy vs Consulting

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct:

1. Immigration Consulting Agency
2. Immigration Conultancy Agency

Per [difference between consulting and consultancy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246489/difference-between-consulting-and-consultancy), `consultancy` is a noun, while `consulting` is an adjective. Not sure if I should be using a noun or adjective in the above case, though.

Comment: consultancy, more used in BrE. consulting, more AmE.

Answer (score 1):

In company titles, "consulting" is more frequently used.

> I work for Smith & Smith, Inc.
>
> What does your company do?
>
> It's an immigration consultancy.

or

> We're immigration consultants.

As opposed to:

> I work for Acme Immigration Consulting, Inc.

But as with any artificial proper name in English, you can always break the rules if you want to.

Comment: Assume it's not an "artificial proper name". "I work for an immigration consulting/consulancy agency" ???

Comment: immigration consultancy or immigration consulting agency.  Agency and consultancy would be redundant.